# An alternate purification process for sugar separation form bee honey?

Tags: organic-chemistry, electrochemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, electrolysis

Bee honey contains 75% sugars (Fructose, Glucose, Maltose, Sucrose and others), some water and low amount of different compounds (up to 5%) [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey).

Basic purification is done by addition of phosphoric acid and calcium hydroxide to form calcium phosphate which is afterwards removed (after precipitation). Then is filtered through activated carbon or ion-exchange resin [Sugar refinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_refinery).

I am looking for a separation process, that can separate the sugars. Is there any other technique or process for removing the rest form the sugars, e.g. some electrochemical separation? First idea would be chromatography, but I would like to separate kilogram(s) of bee honey.

Comment: Are you trying to get a cheaper, easier, or ? alternative to the existing method? Maybe one that would let you sell the sugar as "organic"? Why is the current method not an option?

Comment: That's nice remark. The problem of the standard process is that it is based on the separatation in terms of separate-forgot/destroy. I need all parts of the honey. Even if the sugars have to be removed/destroyed to obtain the rest.